# Angular full server rendering

Tags: angular, iis, single-sign-on, server-side-rendering, angular9

I have just been told that my angular apps needs to be fully rendered on the server. It is currently setup for ssr but from what I have been reading this is just a stop gap until the client has finished loading the page. The reason they have asked, is because it's using Single sign on and there is no pkce setup and it's too late to do so as it's 3rd party controled. Whats the correct method of implementing this in the app and deploying it to an iis server.

Thanks for reading the question.

Comment: This is far too broad a question for SO.

Comment: I just need pointing in the right direction. So I can head down the correct research path

Comment: Have a look at angular universal